# Can Hive deserialize avro bytes to the schema provided?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, avro

I have avro file to be loaded into Hive but my file is in binary.
What deserializer should be used to get the binary avro to hive?

I don't want binary data in hive but the decoded binary data.

This is how I create my table.

CREATE TABLE kst7
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='pathtoavsc.avsc');

When I use the above command table gets created, data gets loaded but when I do a select * from table I get below error:

**Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found bytes, expecting union**

avsc file:

```
{
"namespace": "com.nimesh.tripod.avro.enrichment",
"type": "record",
"name": "EnrichmentData",
"fields": [
    {"name": "rowKey", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
    {"name": "ownerGuid", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
    {"name": "autotagsEnrichment", "type": ["bytes", "null", {
                                                        "namespace": "com.nimesh.tripod.avro.enrichment",
                                                        "type": "record",
                                                        "name": "AutotagEnrichment",
                                                        "fields": [
                                                            {"name": "version", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
                                                            {"name": "autotags", "type": ["null", {"type": "array", "items": {
                                                                                                                                 "namespace": "com.nimesh.tripod.avro.enrichment",
                                                                                                                                 "type": "record",
                                                                                                                                 "name": "Autotag",
                                                                                                                                 "fields": [
                                                                                                                                     {"name": "tag", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
                                                                                                                                     {"name": "score", "type": ["null", "double"], "default": null}
                                                                                                                                 ]
                                                                                                                             }}], "default": null}
                                                        ]
                                                    }], "default": null},
    {"name": "colorEnrichment", "type": ["bytes","null", {
                                                     "namespace": "com.nimesh.tripod.avro.enrichment",
                                                     "type": "record",
                                                     "name": "ColorEnrichment",
                                                     "fields": [
                                                         {"name": "version", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
                                                         {"name": "color", "type": ["null", {"type": "array", "items": {
                                                                                                                           "namespace": "com.nimesh.tripod.avro.enrichment",
                                                                                                                           "type": "record",
                                                                                                                           "name": "Color",
                                                                                                                           "fields": [
                                                                                                                               {"name": "color", "type": ["null", {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}], "default": null},
                                                                                                                               {"name": "score", "type": ["null", "double"], "default": null}
                                                                                                                           ]
                                                                                                                       }}], "default": null}
                                                     ]
                                                 }], "default": null}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `SERDEPROPERTIES` rather than `TBLPROPERTIES`

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='pathtoschema.avsc')
```

Otherwise, try selecting individual fields until you find the one that's causing the error, then inspect what type(s) the AVSC are being mapped into the Hive table as.

Comment: no luck. Actually my avro file have tuples instead of json line. The tuple is (string, string, json, json).

Comment: Can you share your avsc in the question?

Comment: I have added avsc file in the description. Also my avro is a tuples (string, string, <encoded json or map like struct>,  <encoded json or map like struct> ).  When I do getschema for my avro file I get string, string, bytes, bytes

Comment: Sounds like you have bytes, then, not the Avro complex type contained in your data. Side note: for the default values, you ideally list null value first; assuming that field can be null

Comment: Yeah, just ignore the bytes. I had avro complex type contained in my data. Adding bytes was just one of my attempt to get away with the problem.

Comment: I mean, can you download the Avro tools jar file, and extract the data from the Avro file? What do you get? Bytes, or the nested object?

Comment: I only get bytes.

Comment: The avro file is generated using pig (along with UDF). So trying my luck with pig but there are challenges with pig schema to avro schema as well. Also not sure if that conversion is possible or not.